# How to fix my scoring system using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a project, I'm developing code that will check if a certain input value is present at certain locations in the HTML. So I'm checking if a word appears in the headers or titles of graphic content. If a certain word is present, it will be assigned a little green ball, and a red ball if it isn't, I do a number of checks and for different coloured balls, there are different amounts of points assigned to it, still following?, so I've got red, green and orange balls for various checks all with their own if statements. I want to add all these points to create a "totalscore". UPDATED: after all the advice and some good pointers to tutorials I boiled it down to this, but it's still not workin, am I getting closer though?

Here's an example of what I have now:

```
 $("#btnTotalScore").click(function () {
        var totalScore = 0;
        function TitleScore() {
            if ($("#lblMetaTitle").hasClass("orange")) {
                return totalScore += 20;
            } else if ($("#lblMetaTitle").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 25;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        function MetaScore() {
            if ($("#lblMetaDescription").hasClass("orange")) {
                return totalScore += 20;
            } else if ($("#lblMetaDescription").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 25;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        function PresenceScore() {
            if ($("#lblTitle").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 10;
            } else if ($("#lblMeta").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else if ($("#lblAlt").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else if ($("#lblContent").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else if ($("#lblUrl").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        function ContentScore() {
            if ($("#lblContentAmount").hasClass("orange")) {
                return totalScore += 2.5;
            } else if ($("#lblContentAmount").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        function DensityScore() {
            if ($("#lblKeywordDensity").hasClass("orange")) {
                return totalScore += 2.5;
            } else if ($("#lblKeywordDensity").hasClass("green")) {
                return totalScore += 5;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        alert(totalScore);
    });
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: `$("#lblKeywordDensity").attr("class", "circle green")` is not a boolean - it will return a truthy string  always

Comment: It will return `$("#lblKeywordDensity")`, which is indeed truthy. This `switch case` statement makes no sense at all. That's not how you use it. `switch(value){ case "a": doSomething(); case "b": doSomethingElse(); }`

Comment: You can do `if ($("#lblContentAmount").is(".circle, .orange"))  totalScore += 5;`

Comment: The code makes no sense from the beginning. `new TotalScore()` [always returns an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description), adding a number to an object results `NaN` ...

Comment: Also it looks like you need to get familiar with [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of `switch ($("#btnTotalScore").click == true))` you're looking for `$("#btnTotalScore").click( function(){ ....... })`. You want to *execute a function on click* instead of *testing if the click property of a button is true* (which makes no sense).

Then, instead of `case $("#lblMetaTitle").attr("class", "circle orange"):            totalScore+=20;` you're looking for something like `if( $("#lblMetaTitle").hasClass("orange")) totalScore+=20;`

You're using a `switch case` to test if the `click` property of a button is true (?), then for each case that is true, you test if it's equal to the return value of a class assignment (?)
I mean, this code is not even buggy, it just doesn't make sense in the first place (no offense :)
I suggest you go through a bunch of basic tutorials first.